# How do I install the dependencies I need for MySQL::Slurp?

Tags: mysql, perl, moose

I am trying to install the mysqlslurp utility found in [MySQL::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MySQL-Slurp).

I found that it requires [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose) and therefore I installed that package too.

But I am still not able to use the `mysqlslurp` command. I get an error:

```
Can't locate Moose.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi 
.....

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/mysqlslurp line 4.
```

Comment: yes. 64 bit but redhat version for 32 bit

Comment: Did you use CPAN/CPANPLUS shell to install modules?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Moose isn't installed in Perl's include path. You might need to specify the path using `use lib` - see [this article](http://www.devdaily.com/perl/edu/articles/pl010015) for how.

Answer (score 2):

If you install your modules with CPAN.pm (or other CPAN clients), you don't have to handle the dependencies yourself:

```
 % cpan MySQL::Slurp
```

How did you install your modules? Where did you install them?